# How to calculate column difference of Mat in opencv?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, mat

Is there any function to calculate the columnwise of Size(width,1) Mat difference like:
`mat.at(i+1,1)-mat.at(i,1);`
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:    `mat.col(i+1) - mat.col(i)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create two `Mat` from the original one. The first one from column 1 to `cols`, and the second one from column 0 to `cols - 1`, and the use normal subtraction, `mat1 - mat2`.

Answer (score 0):

@Barshan Das answer works great! Just a small addition, for the **entire Mat structure**, to get the difference of columns i+1 and i, I found this useful

```
mat.colRange(1, im.size().width) - mat.colRange(0, im.size().width - 1);
```